# How to fix Unity UI Panel Image being replaced with an "X"?

Tags: unity, image, user-interface

In my Unity Game, the Image on my UI Panel got replaced with an "X" instead of the Image it is supposed to be, I tried adding a different image to the panel and making a new panel, but it still would display the image as an "X", here is an image. [image: The panel's image is replaced by an "X"]

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps needed to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project? Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test proposed fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this problem though, I don't know how it even started, so unfortunately I cannot provide steps to reproduce this error, sorry.

Comment: Then you can work subtractively: make a copy of the project that has the problem, and start deleting stuff from it. Delete as much as you can while still observing the problem with new images you import. That helps narrow down the potential contributing factors.

Comment: It shows that you are looking at the UI element back side, i.e. its dimensions/size is flipped. Because of how relations between dependent RectTransforms work, under some screen sizes some elements can get flipped into negative size.

Answer (score 0):

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4xe5.png)
[[image]

Comment: you have to set these values ​​right..

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it described how a user can identify what values are "right" or "wrong" for fixing this problem.